# Type 'StateManagedSelect' is not generic

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I have a select input from **react-select** lib

when project is mounting it's give me an error which i can close and select will work correctly

here is the error

```
    TS2315: Type 'StateManagedSelect' is not generic.
    34 |   const [continent, setContinent] = useState<string | null>(null);
    35 |
  > 36 |   const withEvent = (option: ValueType<Continents>) => {
       |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    37 |     // debugger
    38 |     setContinent(option)
    39 |   }
```

i can't understand why i get error