# react-select Type 'StateManagedSelect' is not generic

Tags: reactjs, twilio

I am totally newbie using react. I am tried to modify per my requeriments a fork of twilio-react-demo-conversations app.

Here is what I have

```
import { ModalBody, Box } from "@twilio-paste/core";
import { RefObject, useState } from "react";
import ModalInputField from "./ModalInputField";
import AddParticipantFooter from "./addParticipantFooter";
import { ActionName } from "../../types";
import ConvoModal from "./ConvoModal";
import Select from "react-select";
import ValueType from "react-select";

interface AddWhatsAppParticipantModalProps {
  name: string;
  isModalOpen: boolean;
  title: string;
  proxyName: string;
  setName: (name: string) => void;
  setProxyName: (name: string) => void;
  error: string;
  errorProxy: string;
  nameInputRef: RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
  onBack: () => void;
  action: () => void;
  handleClose: () => void;
}

type OptionType = {
  value: string;
  label: string;
};

const twilio_numbers: OptionType[] = [
  { value: "0000000000", label: "0000000000" },
];

const AddWhatsAppParticipantModal: React.FC<AddWhatsAppParticipantModalProps> =
  (props: AddWhatsAppParticipantModalProps) => {
    // SELECT BOX
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] =
      useState<ValueType<OptionType>>();

    const handleChange = (option: ValueType<OptionType>) => {
      setSelectedOption(option);
    };

    return (
      <>
        <ConvoModal
          handleClose={() => props.handleClose()}
          isModalOpen={props.isModalOpen}
          title={props.title}
          modalBody={
            <ModalBody>
              <h3>Añadir Participante de WhatsApp</h3>
              <Box as="form">
                <ModalInputField
                  isFocused={true}
                  label="WhatsApp del Contacto"
                  input={props.name}
                  placeholder="2222222222"
                  onChange={props.setName}
                  error={props.error}
                  help_text="El número WhatsApp del Participante."
                  prefixType="WhatsApp"
                />
                <Select
                  options={twilio_numbers}
                  value={selectedOption as ValueType<OptionType>}
                  onChange={(option) => handleChange(option)}
                />
              </Box>
            </ModalBody>
          }
          modalFooter={
            <AddParticipantFooter
              isSaveDisabled={
                !props.name.trim() || !props.proxyName.trim() || !!props.error
              }
              actionName={ActionName.Save}
              onBack={() => {
                props.onBack();
              }}
              action={props.action}
            />
          }
        />
      </>
    );
  };

export default AddWhatsAppParticipantModal;
```

Error:

```
Type 'StateManagedSelect' is not generic.
    36 |     // SELECT BOX
    37 |     const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] =
  > 38 |       useState<ValueType<OptionType>>();
       |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    39 |
    40 |     const handleChange = (option: ValueType<OptionType>) => {
    41 |       setSelectedOption(option);


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The original file is here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-conversations-demo-react/blob/main/src/components/modals/addWhatsAppParticipant.tsx

Here is an example that I found here what was a guide for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-frost-5bh1o?file=/src/App.tsx:444-478

Also, I found a similar question but no answer yet -> [Type 'StateManagedSelect' is not generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74060557/type-statemanagedselect-is-not-generic)

What do I need: I need a select box which replaces the input field that push props.proxyName / setProxyName. I want to display a predetermined list of phone numbers instead write one.

Thanks and sorry if my english is bad.
Best regards